# Building Ember Models using only one API call

Tags: ember.js, model

Currently, I get all the JSON from the server in one API call. I'm wondering, how can I make multiple models to use for the different routes from this? The way I'm currently doing it is by putting it in a huge model, and then accessing the smaller parts from the different routes. Would this be the right approach?

Comment: Do you mean sideloading the data?

Comment: I did some googling around and yes, I do think I mean that.

Comment: If you have Ember data setup, then it should [sideload](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships) any models in a API response, so you can access them from the store without making another API call.